# OpenCV BoW descriptors empty bins

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I think this is a repeat of a few questions previously by [Michele](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774314/get-descriptors-from-bowimgdescriptorextractorcompute) and [Joshua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247169/opencv-bowimgdescriptorextractor-empty-histogram). But I need to ask the question again as none of the others have been answered.

I am trying to do image classification using BoW approach. I have looked into some tutorials that show up on google search and documentation on OpenCV website. For features, I first divide the image into a grid and compute histogram and stack them to form a set of descriptors for each image. Then for all the descriptors extracted for the training images in my database, I use BOWKMeansTrainer to build a dictionary.

For my test images, when I try to generate the BoW feature vector using BOWImgDescriptorExtractor, the histogram of the BoW is coming out empty for all my test images. Here is a brief part of the code...

```cpp
class histFeatureExtractor : public cv::DescriptorExtractor
{
...
};

...
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorMatcher> matcher(new cv::FlannBasedMatcher);
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> extractor(new histFeatureExtractor); 
cv::BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowDE(extractor,matcher);
bowDE.setVocabulary(dictionary); /// dictionary computed earlier
```

Then for each of my training images, I compute,

```
bowDE.compute(img,keypoints1,bowDescTest);
```

NOTE: keypoints1 does not contain any keypoints but since opencv wants a non-empty container, I have put some junk values in it. Since I am using my own descriptor extractor (which gets called properly)... I don't need any keypoints.

in the end, my bowDescTest should contain the descriptor computed for the test image, but it is coming out to be  `[ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]`

I don't understand if my logic is incorrect or if the choice of features was wrong ... or there is something in the usage of OpenCV function that I have mistaken in... Could anyone please help.

EDIT: 19-12-2013: 20:59 
//////********************************************//////
CLASS THAT COMPUTES THE HISTOGRAM DESCRIPTORS

```
class histFeatureExtractor : public cv::DescriptorExtractor
{
public:
    histFeatureExtractor() : cv::DescriptorExtractor()/*, m_patchSize(cv::Size(136,160))*/
    {
        /// Width, Height
        m_patchSize = cv::Size(80,160);
    }

    ~histFeatureExtractor()
    {
    }

    void compute( const cv::Mat& __img,
                  CV_OUT CV_IN_OUT std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>& __keypoints,
                  CV_OUT cv::Mat& __descriptors ) const
    {
        this->computeImpl(__img, __keypoints, __descriptors);
    }

    int descriptorSize() const {return 128;}
    int descriptorType() const {return CV_32F;}

    bool empty() const { return false; }

protected:
    void computeImpl( const cv::Mat& __img, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>& keypoints, cv::Mat& __descriptors ) const
    {
        //cv::namedWindow("Patch");
        float range[] = { 0, 256 } ;
        const float* histRange = { range };
        bool uniform = true; bool accumulate = false;
        int histSize = 256;

        //int count = 0;
        cv::Mat transp;
        for (int r=0; r<__img.rows/m_patchSize.height ; ++r)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<__img.cols/m_patchSize.width ; ++c)
            {
                //std::cout << "[" << r << "  " << c << "]: ";
                /// Construct image patches
                std::vector<cv::Mat> bgr_planes;

                cv::Point patchTopLeft( m_patchSize.width*c, m_patchSize.height*r);
                cv::Rect imgPatch(patchTopLeft, m_patchSize);
                cv::split( __img(imgPatch), bgr_planes );

                //cv::imshow("Patch", __img(imgPatch));

                cv::Mat b_hist, g_hist, r_hist;

                cv::Mat transp_CV32F;

                /// Compute the histograms:
                cv::calcHist( &bgr_planes[0], 1, 0, cv::Mat(), b_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
                transp = b_hist.t();
                transp.convertTo(transp_CV32F, CV_32F);
                __descriptors.push_back(transp_CV32F);
                cv::calcHist( &bgr_planes[1], 1, 0, cv::Mat(), g_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
                transp = g_hist.t();
                transp.convertTo(transp_CV32F, CV_32F);
                __descriptors.push_back(transp_CV32F);
                cv::calcHist( &bgr_planes[2], 1, 0, cv::Mat(), r_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
                transp = r_hist.t();
                transp.convertTo(transp_CV32F, CV_32F);
                __descriptors.push_back(transp_CV32F);
            }
        }
    }
private:
    cv::Size m_patchSize;
};
```

PARTS OF MAIN CODE

```
histFeatureExtractor featureExtractor;
std::cout << "Generating vocabulary..."; 
for (int i=0 ; i<ntrainImgs ; ++i)
{
    cv::Mat desc;
    std::string imgName( __mTrainData.getImage( i ) );
    std::string imgFullPath = __mTrainData.m_workingDirectory + "/" + imgName;
    img = cv::imread( imgFullPath );

    featureExtractor.compute( img, keypoints, desc );

    cv::Mat desc_CV32F;
    desc.convertTo(desc_CV32F, CV_32F); /// I READ SOMEWHERE THAT BoW class is looking for CV_32F format, so forcing every thing to be in that format.
    bowTrainer.add(desc_CV32F);
    cv::imshow("Current Frame", img);
    std::cout << ".";
}

/// Generating BoW descriptors
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorMatcher> matcher(new cv::FlannBasedMatcher);
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> extractor(new histFeatureExtractor);
cv::BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowDE(extractor,matcher);
bowDE.setVocabulary(dictionary);


for (int i=0 ; i<ntestImgs ; ++i)
{
    std::string imgName( __mTestData.getImage( i ) );
    std::string imgFullPath = __mTestData.m_workingDirectory + "/" + imgName;
    img = cv::imread( imgFullPath );

    cv::Mat bowDescTest;
    /// NOTE: EMPTY KEYPOINTS
    /// I checked this part in the opencv file 
    /// /DEV/opencv_2-4-0/sources/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/features2d/src/bagofwords.cpp
    /// function BOWImgDescriptorExtractor::compute(...) 
    /// Line 141 onwards. This function is exclusively used 
    /// by the extractor, which in my case is not required.
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints1(30);

    bowDE.compute(img,keypoints1,bowDescTest);
    std::cout << bowDescTest.type() << std::endl;

    /// Print the BoW descriptors
    ///
    /// HERE I GET THE DESCRIPTORS TO BE ALL ZEROS.
    std::cout << i << " : [ ";
    for (int r=0 ; r<bowDescTest.rows ; ++r)
    {
        for (int c=0 ; c<bowDescTest.cols ; ++c)
        {
            std::cout << cvRound( bowDescTest.at<float>(r,c) ) << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "]\n";
}
```

Comment: Please post code that lets me replicate your problem. A minimal (non-)working example would be great.

Comment: I updated the question Unapiedra.